# Selecting only values that occur more than once in a field

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

I have a field that contains different values, some which occur more than once in the field. How do I select only the values that occur more than once?

Example

[image]

I only want to select rows that contain 'AMK' in the Subzone field as they occur more than once. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use select by expression and then use this expression:

```
if(count("fieldname","fieldname")>1,true,false)
```

replace "fieldname" with the name of your field. `>1` means to select all rows which value appears more than once in the column "fieldname". You can use any number here.

Answer (score 0):

MrXSquared is spot on with the expression. For the record, you can also make a Virtual Layer. It will not select the records but return a temporal layer with field value counts, if you need a general overview:

```
select count(*) count, Subzone, geometry 
from mytable
group by Subzone
order by 1 desc
```